# How to find devices within a region based on their latitude and longitude in ThnigsBorad

Tags: thingsboard

I have connected my devices to things-board and periodically they are sending their Geo-coordinates (latitude, longitude) as device telemetry. I need to query and find the devices within a region based on their latitude and longitude.

the definition of region can be:

1. radius + Lat + Lon
2. top-left coordinates + bottom right coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a GPS geofencing filter into your rulechain.

The messages that have coordinates within your defined area will be passed out as True.

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/filter-nodes/